# Get the data from EXEC statement?

Tags: sql-server

When I execute the query in mssql, the data is not displayed. How can I get the Data from the EXEC statement query?
My Query is

```
DECLARE @TableName  VARCHAR
    SET     @TableName  ='Nums'
    EXEC    (
                'SELECT *
                FROM    '+"@TableName

            )
```

Please guide me where am i wrong?

Comment: Remove `"` there, and why you'r using varchar instead of nvarchar, and why not sp_executesql.

Comment: This is wide open to injection. You should be using `QUOTENAME` on any dynamic object names, and parametrising dynamic SQL where you can (by uise of `sp_executesql`, like @Sami mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

I'll do it like

```
DECLARE @TableName SysName = N'Nums';
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName);

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Finally, I would suggest that you visit **[`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** and **[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)** by Erland Sommarskog.